# Optimize the procedure in Informix

Tags: sql, database, informix

I need to optimize the Procedure below. Syntax should be in Informix.
Here a table update is required with sequential update. It seems to be very large.Can it be optimized.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ENTRY() LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE record integer;
DECLARE txaa_id bigint;
DECLARE id bigint;
DECLARE createDatetimed timestamp;
DECLARE idPlus bigint;

set record = 0;--
set txaa_id = 0;--
set id = 0;--
set idPlus = 0;--
set createDatetimed = null;--


FOR v_row1 as select distinct txaa_id from finalBaseData
DO
        FOR v_row2  as select txsa_id , finalBaseData.txaa_id , finalBaseData.createdatetime from  tx_status_audit,finalBaseData where tx_status_audit.txaa_id  = v_row1.txaa_id and tx_status_audit.txaa_id = finalBaseData.txaa_id and tx_status_audit.cdts = 'OUT' order by tx_status_audit.create_datetime desc fetch first 1 rows only

        DO
        set record = record + 1;

                IF ( record = 1)
                THEN
                set id = v_row2.txsa_id;
                set idPlus = id + 1;
                set txaa_id = v_row2.txaa_id;
                set createDatetimed = v_row2.createdatetime;
                END IF;
        END FOR;

        insert into tx_status_audit values (idPlus,'CMPT',txaa_id,'HWNG',createDatetimed);
        set record = 0;
        set idPlus = 0;
        set txaa_id = 0;
        set createDatetimed = null;
END FOR;
END;
```

Comment: It looks like that a simple insert select statement would easily solve this... I will let you figure it out. Since you did not demonstrated any effort in how to solve it.

Comment: i just wrote it, I new, I thought it can be optimize.

Comment: Yes it can. And I said how you should do it. I will not provide an answer since besides the existent code you didn't provide anything that show some attempt to solve it. Search how to do a insert select statement, then how to use a subquery inside a select statement. Try it, and if you can't get it to work post it here, we will help. As it is seems that it is an existent code and you hope someone will do your work to you... sorry we wont.